# Fail to allocate Bitmap Error using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory, error-handling

For every column of the csv file I am plotting a graph and saving it,
I am facing problem with saving all the png images. After approximately 260 images it throws error Fail to allocate Bitmap and code stops executing

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm,skew
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import skew
```

```
df=pd.read_csv()  //address of the csv file
address=          //address in which images are stored
for col in df.columns:                    

                plt.hist(df[col],density=True,alpha=0.6,color='g',rwidth=0.8)
                
                #----->Adding the Gaussian Curve which requires only mean and Sigma
                xmin,xmax=plt.xlim()                       #------->Takes the max and min value from the previous graph
                #xmin,xmax=col_min,col,max
                x=np.linspace(xmin,xmax,100)               #------------------------------------->Can Change this 100 to run FASTER
                p=norm.pdf(x,col_mean,col_std)     
                plt.plot(x,p,'k',linewidth=2,label="Gaussian Curve")  

    

                
                #---->Plotting the Kernal Density Estimation
                #---->Bandwidth Selection is Silverman
                #---->bw_adjust will control the sensitivity of the plot 0.2 more variable and sensitive by defalut it is one               
                kde=sns.kdeplot(df[col],bw_method='silverman',bw_adjust=1,color='blue',linestyle="solid",linewidth=2,label="Kernal Density Estimation")

                #---->Customize the legend
                plt.legend()         

                #----->SAVING THE IMAGES AT A GIVEN LOCATION
                i=i+1


                plt.title(col)
                #Error because we cannot use : in the name of the file of the parameter
                plt.savefig(address+ "/" +str(i)+ "_" +".png")      #------------------->HARD CODED

                plt.close()
```

Is there any way to remove this issue or how to use try except block to overcome this issue. Even on using try except block the code does not go to the except block